# Eloquent Model Many to One Relationship

Tags: php, orm, model, eloquent, relationship

Take this example:

I have a table `users` with fields as `id`, `name`, `city`. I have another table, which contains name of the cities. The table name is `cities` and fields are: `id`, `name`. So, I store the id (primary key) of a city in the `city` column of the table `users`. While getting an user Eloquent model, what is the best way to get the name of the city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention you would name your relation `city()`, but there is also an attribute `city` being foreign key, so you can't access the related model.

If so, then I suggest renaming the foreign key to `city_id` or something like that, then it will work:

```
$user->city; // City model
$user->city->name;
```

Otherwise, if you can't change the schema, then rename relationship:

```
// User model
public funciton relatedCity()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('City', 'city');
}

// then
$user->relatedCity->name;
```

Comment: Yes, I missed the "_id" part of the column name to use belongsTo relationship, which is the inverse of one to one relationship. It works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already configured the Models

```
// find a user named John
$user = User::where('name', '=', 'John')->first();

// get the city of the user
$userCity = $user->city;
```

Comment: `$user->city` returns `id` of the city. I need the `name` of the city.

Comment: $userCity = City::where('id', '=', $user->city)->first(); and then you can get name by $userCity->name;

Comment: Yes, I can do this. But I am looking for a solution in Eloquent ORM using relationships.